# Add output to another process running from cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron, pty

I see many questions about getting the output from another process. This question is about the opposite: injecting into the STDOUT of another process.

I have a daily cron job (a Bash script doing a rsync backup). In some cases, it would be running for more than 24 hours. So the following day, before starting the backup again, my script checks to see if yesterday's backup is still running. If it is, the script `kill`s that unfinished backup before starting.

What I would like is to **add a line to the output of yesterday's cron job before killing it**, so that the email cron will send with the output contains a line explaining what happened.

When I kill my cron job, the output in the email we get ends with

```
/bin/sh: line 1: 132887 Terminated              /usr/local/bin/backup-to-external
```

I would like cron's email to (also) contain something like

```
Backup was still running. Terminating it before starting it again.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the cronjob to execute a bash script if it already isn't. Inside the script, write a signal handler that outputs your message and terminates your process. Something like below,

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -f "/path/to/my/binary.pid" ]]; then
    already_running_pid=$(cat "/path/to/my/binary.pid")
    echo "I'm new ($$). Terminating old."
    kill -15 $already_running_pid
    wait $already_running_pid
fi

/path/to/your/binary <some args> &
my_binary_pid=$!
echo $$ > /path/to/my/binary.pid

function stop_services() {
  kill -9 $my_binary_pid
  echo "I'm old ($$). Being Terminated."
}

trap stop_services SIGTERM
wait
rm /path/to/my/binary.pid
```

Your cron should run this bash script and not your /path/to/your/binary.